# How to solve logical issue with Laravel - Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I have $win->start, $article->from and $article->days

Now I want to create HTML like this:

```
if ($article->from)  >  (Carbon::now()->addDays($article->days))  {
    $r = Carbon::now()->addDays($article->days)
    if ($r > $win->start) {
    <div>get VOUCHER</div>
        }
    else {
    <div>ACTIVE</div>
    }
    else {
    $r = $article->from
    if ($r > $win-> start) {
    <div>get VOUCHER</div>
        }
    else {
    <div>ACTIVE</div>
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this logical problem with proper Blade - Carbon code... How to create two if into blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
 @foreach($wins as $win)
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
             <p>{{ date('d M Y', strtotime($win->start)) }}</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
             <p><strong>{{$win->price}} </strong>euros</p>
         </div>
     @if($article->from > \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays($article->days))
         {{ $r = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays($article->days) }}
         @if($r > $win->start) 
             <div>get VOUCHER</div>
         @else
            <div>ACTIVE</div>
         @endif
     @else
        {{ $r = $article->from }}
        @if($r > $win-> start)
            <div>get VOUCHER</div>
        @else
            <div>ACTIVE</div>
        @endif
    @endif
 </div>
 <hr style="margin:0px;">
@endforeach
```

**UPDATED:** With your full snippet

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures

Comment: but now I have: https://jsfiddle.net/0yapeesv/ and I get error:1/1
FatalErrorException in cec442d81d7219ffeb3d7a5027d49adb line 82:
syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)